# sizeof() of a structure containing an unordered_map as a member

Tags: c++, structure, sizeof, unordered-map

I have a structure of the following type

```
struct Node
    {
        int  word;       
        int   count;       
        unordered_map<Type, Node*> map;       

    }node;
```

Is it safe to assume that sizeof(node) gives you the correct size of that node in C++? 
I am sure there will be padding in the structure but still will the sizeof take into consideration the correct size of the unordered_map.

Comment: What do you mean by safe? If you are worried that size may change after some time then don't worry.

Comment: sorry about the confusion I have edited it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, since `sizeof` is usually calculated at compile time.

That means that even if the hash size is 1000 or 100 or 10 or 1 or 0 you will get the same sizeof result.
don't assume it will be enlarged even if the hash table will be modified.

however remember that sizeof in c++ can have awkward results sometimes (padding, place for the virutal table pointer, etc...)

Comment: offtopic: for some call sizeof usage see exceptional c++ book templates section. sizeof has more power to it than you might think in first glance

Comment: `sizeof` is *always* computed at compile time.