# Size in bytes of a structure containing unordered_map

Tags: c++, size, byte, unordered-map

Need to find the exact size in bytes, occupied by a tree data structure that I have implemented. Node Structure is as follows

```
struct Node
{
    int  word;       
    int   count;       
    unordered_map<int, Node*> map;       

}node;
```

What I have been doing is 
size(int)*2(for word and count) + map.bucket_count() * (sizeof(int) + sizeof(Node*)) and repeatedly do this for each node. 
Is this the correct way of doing this if i am neglecting the element overhead of storage in the unordered_map?

Also, if I am correct map.bucket_count() gives the number of buckets that are currently allocated that is including the pre- allocated ones. Should I be using map.size() instead which will ignore the pre-allocated buckets?

Or instead of all this, is it better to use tools like MemTrack to find the memory used?

Comment: Since each bucket of a hash map contains a variable number of entries, you'll be able to make a stab at the size of an empty node, but a node with children will have variable size.

Comment: If you want to do an experiment, you could just replace the new-operator and follow observe the allocations as you insert elements into the map.

Comment: yes ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: possible duplicate of [sizeof() of a structure containing an unordered_map as a member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420317/sizeof-of-a-structure-containing-an-unordered-map-as-a-member)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or instead of all this, is it better to use tools like MemTrack to find the memory used?

Yes. There's no telling from the outside how much memory an `unordered_map` or other complex, opaque object takes, and a good memory profiler might also show you how much overhead the memory allocator itself takes.

Comment: Hey thanks larsman.Is MemTrack a good profiler, or is there a better one?

Comment: I don't know this MemTrack. I tend to do memory profiling very roughly using good-old `top` :)